# svn log search for specific description

Tags: svn

Is there a way to investigate for a description on svn log, like:

```
svn log | grep "desc"
```

that also return revision number, user and not just the description string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Subversion 1.8, there's an option `--search`, so you would just do:

```
svn log --search desc
```

Here's a [link to the corresponding release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search).

If you're stuck with an older version of Subversion, the following should help in most cases (except if the log messages span multiple lines - adjust the "before" parameter as needed):

```
svn log | grep -B3 desc
```